# Copy a tree recursively in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, recursion, meteor, meteorite, meteor-up

I am working on a Meteorjs application where I have a syllabus and I want to copy or clone this syllabus. Here in my syllabus there are modules which can till multiple levels means a mudule can have another module as its child module and so on.for example i have a module Grammer and grammer has another module named tenses and tenses ahs some other module named present past and future these will seems like this.

```
tenses
    past
        simple
        negative
        interogative
    present
        simple
        negative
        interogative
    future
        simple
        negative
        interogative
```

databse fields are 
                        name,
                        parent_id,
                        has_children,
                        syllabus_id
these mudules can further have some sub modules or children.
In database to check if a module have further children i have a field boolean `has_children` and `parent_id` to relate the child with the parent.If element is a root element its 'parent_id` will be null.

for this i tried to reach every element recursively but i am able to reach only one element at one level. means i am not reaching to the siblings of an element but the children.

My code is :

```
cloneSyllabus:function(syllabi_id){
    syll_obj=Meteor.syllabi.findOne({_id:syllabi_id});
    new_syllabi_id=Meteor.syllabi.insert({

                                        subject_id:syll_obj.subject_id,
                                        level_id:syll_obj.level_id,
                                    });
    var parent_objs = Meteor.collecton.find({
                                              parent_id:null, 
                                              syllabus_id:syllabi_id}).fetch()

    for(var i=0;i<syll_design_objs.length;i++){
        makeClone(parent[i],null,new_syllabi_id)    
    }
}
```

and the other function which is creating the objects recursively is

```
function makeClone(item,parent_id,syllabi_id){
    var item_id=item._id
    delete item._id
    item.parent_id=parent_id
    item.syllabus_id=syllabi_id
    var new_parent_id=Meteor.syllabi_design.insert(item)
    if(item.has_children){
        child_items=Meteor.collection.find({parent_id:item_id}).fetch();
        for(i=0;i<child_items.length;i++){
            makeClone(child_items[i],item_id,syllabi_id);
        }
    }
}
```

But using this i am able to retrieve only one element at the same level but not its siblings.
i will be able to create 
    tenses
        past
            simple
            negative
            interogative
tell me guys where i am making a mistake while retrieving these objects.Or tell me any otherway to accomplish the task.
Here i have to change only the syllabus_id and create all the objects again.

Comment: It seems you have a good idea of what you want done. What is your actual problem? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: if your objects are plain simple (no classes or anything), try EJSON.clone. Might be enough. In more complex cases you would need to think and code up a tree traversal :)

Comment: Yes I tried something, I am editing the question and posting my code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is perfect in your code just add recursive function termination statement in your code.
    cloneSyllabus:function(syllabi_id){
    syll_obj=Meteor.syllabi.findOne({_id:syllabi_id});
    new_syllabi_id=Meteor.syllabi.insert({

```
                                    subject_id:syll_obj.subject_id,
                                    level_id:syll_obj.level_id,
                                });
var parent_objs = Meteor.collecton.find({
                                          parent_id:null, 
                                          syllabus_id:syllabi_id}).fetch()

for(var i=0;i<syll_design_objs.length;i++){
    makeClone(parent[i],null,new_syllabi_id)    
}
return 
}
```

And declare the variable `i` as `var i` and `child_objs` as `var child_objs` in loop of the function `makeClone` because these variable are being treated here as a glabal variable in your code.

```
function makeClone(item,parent_id,syllabi_id){
    var item_id=item._id
    delete item._id
    item.parent_id=parent_id
    item.syllabus_id=syllabi_id
    var new_parent_id=Meteor.syllabi_design.insert(item)
    if(item.has_children){
        child_items=Meteor.collection.find({parent_id:item_id}).fetch();
        for(var j=0;j<child_items.length;j++){
            makeClone(child_items[i],item_id,syllabi_id);
        }
    }
    else{
        return
    }
    }
```

Hope this will work perfect for you